# 1 / 0 give me java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

Why `1.0d / 0.0` give `NaN` but `1 / 0` give me `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`, why for the 1st case also I did not got `ArithmeticException`

Comment: Because the rules for floating-point and integer arithmetic are different.

Comment: That should give you `Infinity` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: @RohitJain perhaps in JavaScript, but strictly speaking it is nonsense. The result is not defined. Then, what would 0/0 should be in your opinion.

Comment: @JiriKremser `0/0` would give the same `/ by zero` exception. However, `0.0 / 0.0` will give `NaN`.

Comment: @JiriKremser The result is as per IEEE 754 standard, and not per language.

Comment: I see, I was speaking "math" and you were speaking "IEEE 754". I haven't noticed the tag.